# Devise Session destroy with ajax request how should I approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, jquery, devise

I have a form where user can fill in the details the form field contain an **email_id** column

Now **if the user is logged in** there would **appear a link** stating

"**NOT USER NAME**"  e.g "**NOT VIREN NEGI**" against that email field which would be a ajax request.to destroy the devise session

Once user click the link the devise session would be destroyed and on success of ajax the above anchor tag would be disapper

I have implemented this solution by Moneypatching the destroy method of Devise like

```
class DeviseSessionsController < DeviseController

  def destroy
    .... DEVISE CODE ...
    .... DEVISE CODE ...
    .... DEVISE CODE ...

     respond_to do |format|
       if request.xhr? **## My Hack**
         format.js { render :partial => 'users/signout' } **## render signout partial on ajax request** 
       else 
         format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
        format.all do
          method = "to_#{request_format}"
          text = {}.respond_to?(method) ? {}.send(method) : ""
          render :text => text, :status => :ok
       end
     end 
    end
  end
end
```

This all though seem to work but since but I'm not happy with this

1. does not suit if devise updated and in future destroy method might look different what it is currently
2. I have copy all the other action method of devise/sessions_controller to have devise working without any problem

Can anyone Help me on this

Please Avoid answering that monkeypatching is bad asking me to read about monkeypatching all those stuff (I know that) that why the question is posted.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use devise helper method signout

create a action inside users controller

```
def log_me_out 
   signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js  { render :partial => 'log_me_out',:layout => false }
    end
end
```

This will save you from moneypatching devise#sessions controller

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add csrf meta tag to request. I think this is the problem, not in devise.

this should solve it

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-      token']").attr('content')); }
});
```

Comment: @Oboza,I guess you miss understood the question the question is to detect better way to signout devise session then the one presented by me in question(i.e monkeypathcing) .with my above code I able to destroy the session  but I not happy with monkeypatching solution. I you have a better solution it would be very helpful